# using datatable with jquery&ajax,DT gives unkown parameter error

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

This is Datatable structure

```
function loadseries(){
    seriesTab = $('#series_table').dataTable({   
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bDestroy"  : true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort" : false,
            "sDom": "rt",
             "iDisplayLength": -1,
            "sAjaxSource": "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sam/relative/loadchild?id="+$('#id').val(),
                "aoColumns": [ 
                              { "mData": "index"}, 
                              { "mData": "childName" },
                              { "mData": "sex" },
                              { "mData": "child_dob" },
                              { "mData": "childId","sClass": "center",
                               "mRender": function () {
                                   return ' <a href="javascript:myDel();" tabindex="-1" id="delete" class="editor_remove"><img  alt="" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/delete.png" /></a>';
                                    },

                              } 
                                  ]    


    });
}
```

and here is my function to add row dynamicaly

```
$('#add').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();     
        if($("#addform").valid()){ 
            var anNodes = $("#series_table tbody tr");
            var tLen=anNodes.length;
            var rowData = seriesTab.fnGetData( anNodes[0] );
            if(rowData==null)
                var index=1;
            else
                index=tLen+1;
        fnClickAddRow(index,$('#childName').val(),$('#sex').val(),$('#child_dob').val());   
        e.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });

    function fnClickAddRow(index,childName,sex,child_dob) {
    var chk=0;
    var anNodes = $("#series_table tbody tr");
    alert("Function begining : "+index+" "+childName+" "+sex+ " "+child_dob);
    alert("length " +anNodes.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < anNodes.length; ++i){   
    var rowData = seriesTab.fnGetData( anNodes[i] );
    alert("In loop childName : "+rowData.childName);
    if(rowData!=null){
        //alert(rowData[0]+"  "+rowData[1]+"  "+rowData[2]+ " "+rowData[3]);
        if(rowData[1]==childName){
         alert("inside if ");  
    chk=1;
     break;
    }}}
    alert("After Foor Loop : "+index+" "+childName+" "+sex+ " "+child_dob);
        seriesTab.fnAddData( [
        index,
        childName,
        sex,
        child_dob,
        '<a href="javascript:myDel();" tabindex="-1" id="delete" class="editor_remove"><img  alt="" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/delete.png" /></a>'] );
        seriesClear();

} 
function seriesClear()
{
    $('#childName').val('');
    $('#childName').focus();
    }
```

**when i am going to add the row it gives series_table requesting for unkown parameter index from datasourse**

i am new to datatable please help me out ..

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 columns in your DT as per your code shown below:

```
{ "mData": "index"}, 
{ "mData": "childName" },
{ "mData": "sex" },
{ "mData": "child_dob" },
{ "mData": "childId","sClass": "center",
  "mRender": function () {
        return ' <a href="javascript:myDel();" tabindex="-1" id="delete" class="editor_remove"><img  alt=""   src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/delete.png" /></a>';
},
```

But you are adding only 4 columns in your `fnClickAddRow`

```
fnClickAddRow(index,$('#childName').val(),$('#sex').val(),$('#child_dob').val());
```

Did you notice that???

and you have declared `index` inside `if`

```
if(rowData==null)
     var index=1;
else
     index=tLen+1;
```

**To be on safer side put it outside and assign it inside!!**

Comment: Thanks @Guruprasad Rao *the 5th column thats is a icon is adding below at last time  and i have also declared var index outside but problem is still same ...*

Comment: I think _you need to add that icon everytime when you add a record_

Comment: Thanks @Guruprasad i am addind icon each time when a row is dynamically added, and it is showing in DT when a row is added but rest all columns is not adding ..

Comment: can you update your question and let me know how you are adding that icon into newly added row??

Comment: in above function loadseries() the 5th column code is of icon adding.